# call COM object from Program Files folder need to run manually

Tags: .net, com, registry

I am working on .NET app which has COM object and etc. and created SETUP with `InstallShield`

I'm registering this COM object `MyCom.exe` with `REGASM` successfully.

The `exe` located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\XYZ\MyCom.exe` it needs to run `exe` manually.

I am sure this is not a permissions problem and all things in registry is OK. When I am trying to change URL in `LocalServer32` value to `C:\Test\MyCOM.exe` it works.
May be problem with `InstallShield` made some problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a space in the path. Trying putting quotes around it when you put it into the registry.

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\XYZ\MyCom.exe"`

Comment: Then what should I do, regasm doesn't put queotes

Comment: @EminHasanov : Did you figure it out? I'm surprised regasm doesn't put quotes.